# How can I filter from a select statement having an aggregate function?

Tags: sql-server

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
    FirstName, 
    LastName, 
    SD.SalesOrderID, 
    SO.CustomerID, [Status], 
    OrderDate, 
    COUNT(OrderQty) AS Count_of_Items, 
    SUM(OrderQty) AS TotalQty, 
    AVG(OrderQty) AS Average, 
    AVG(OrderQty) FILTER(WHERE TotalQty>300) AS 'Over 300'
```

The Select statement above gives a syntactic error here "FILTER(WHERE TotalQty>300)" , my intention is to filter in another column average values for sum of OrderQty greater than 300.

Comment: Please show us the entire query, as well as sample data and expected results.

Answer (score 0):

SQL Server does not implement `FILTER` clause. Conditional aggregation could be emulated with `CASE` expression:

```
AVG(CASE WHEN TotalQty>300 THEN OrderQty END) AS [Over 300]
<=>
AVG(OrderQty) FILTER(WHERE TotalQty>300) AS 'Over 300'
```

Explanation: For values of TotalQty lower or equal 300, the case expression returns NULL(default) and NULL values are ignored by AVG aggregate function.

Comment: *If*, as the query seems to indicate, `TotalQty` is an alias for aggregate function `SUM(OrderQty)`, would this work?

Comment: @GMB In such scenario SUM has to be calculated first(subquery) and  AVG should be calculated on outerquery.

Comment: Below is the question. Not allowed to use subquery.List the order's customer name, order status, date ordered, count of items on the order, and average quantity ordered where the count of items on the order is greater than 300.

Comment: SELECT DISTINCT FirstName, LastName, SD.SalesOrderID, SO.CustomerID, [Status], OrderDate, COUNT(OrderQty) AS Count_of_Items,  SUM(OrderQty) AS TotalQty, AVG(OrderQty) AS Average,
AVG(OrderQty) FILTER(WHERE TotalQty>300) AS 'Over 300'
FROM Sales.SalesOrderHeader AS SO
JOIN Person.Person PP ON SO.CustomerID=PP.BusinessEntityID
JOIN Sales.SalesOrderDetail SD ON SO.SalesOrderID=SD.SalesOrderID
Group By SD.SalesOrderID, OrderQty, SO.CustomerID, OrderDate, FirstName, LastName,[Status]
ORDER BY SD.SalesOrderID
GO
My full query above

Answer (score 0):

As per your whole query in the comment, taken from *AdventureworksDB*, I've corrected the join condition of `Person` table. Also, just like *Lukasz* mentioned in his answer, using a `CASE` to 'filter' the required condition of SUM(OrderQty) > 300.

```
SELECT  FirstName,
        LastName,
        SD.SalesOrderID,
        SO.CustomerID,
        [Status], OrderDate, 
        COUNT(OrderQty) AS Count_of_Items, 
        SUM(OrderQty) AS TotalQty, AVG(OrderQty) AS Average,
        case when SUM(OrderQty) > 300  then AVG(OrderQty) end as 'Over 300' 
FROM Sales.SalesOrderHeader AS SO 
JOIN Person.Person PP ON SO.SalesPersonID=PP.BusinessEntityID 
JOIN Sales.SalesOrderDetail SD ON SO.SalesOrderID=SD.SalesOrderID  
Group By SD.SalesOrderID,SO.CustomerID, OrderDate, FirstName, LastName,[Status]
ORDER BY SD.SalesOrderID
```

Comment: Thank you for the correction. I can now see why I was having difficulty with the query.